# Dot/point in datagridview when updating data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

So, I have a datagridview (datagridview1) and it's connected to SQL Server. datagridview in column 3 (adhb) can be update by pressing a button and just edit in the specific column. The problem is when I try to update a decimal number (e.g 100.25) it's just change to 10025. How can it be able to update decimal value?

The database (tbl_tahunan), and column 3 (adhb) is set to decimal(18,2)

query for update data

```
query = "UPDATE tbl_tahunan SET adhb = " + datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value + " WHERE id_coicop = 1";

cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. (it'll maybe even solve your current problem without you having to do anything else)

Comment: Where does it change to 10025? In the grid or in the db? (Do you see it as 100.25 in the grid but it saves to db as 10025, or does it always flick to 10025 when you try typing 100.25 into the grid?). Show some screenshots of the process and how you discover it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Editing databases with data grids is ridiculously easy if you make life easy. Try doing this:

- Make a brand new project, so you don't disturb existing code
- Add a new file of type DataSet
- Open it by double clicking
- Right click anywhere on the surface, choose Add.. TableAdapter
- Fill in the connection details of the db
- Choose "SELECT that produces rows"
- Put a query of `SELECT * FROM tbl_tahunan`
- Finish the wizard
- Switch to the form
- Open the Data Sources tool panel (View menu, Other Windows submenu)
- Expand the nodes in the name of your dataset
- Drag the tbl_tahunan one onto the form
- Run the program

Yes, that's it, not a single line of code written by you; VS has done it all (and made a better job of it too) and this simple app will download, display, edit and save rows. And I bet it won't have any decimal problems either..

You can look at how it works by reading the code in .Designer.cs files: the datagridview is connected to a datatable (tbl_tahunandatatable) through a bindingSource. When you fill the table with data, you will see the grid show the data automatically. You do not need to interact with the datagridview cells collection. All programmatic editing of data should be done to the datatable. This is a concept called MVC (model- the datatable, view - the datagridview, controller - sometimes the datagridview in editing mode, other times something else) - keeping M separate from VC usually helps build a sensible program structure

You can build on this simple app you've created by e.g.:

- opening dataset,
- right clicking on the TableAdapter,
- adding another query,
- add a query with some relevant where clause (llike `SELECT * FROM tbl_tahunan WHERE adhb BETWEEN @from AND @to`)
- call it a good name, like FillByAdhbBetween
- putting some text boxes in the UI
- putting a button on the ui that calls it:

```
tbl_tahunanTableAdapter.FillByAdhbBetween(somedatasetname.tbl_tahunan, Convert.ToDecimal(adhbfromTextbox.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(adhbtoTextbox.Text))
```

Now the grid will only fill with some rows instead of all

Personally I always make the first query in a table adapter have a WHERE clause, that selects by primary key. It is handy for loading related data. We almost never want to select all rows from a db into our program